# Parametric string replacement

Tags: java, parameters, substitution

I am running in to bit of a trouble trying to use parametric replacement.

In my properties file I have the following entry

```
tpi.message=This is a test message. Generated for ? on ? .
```

The  text above is displayed on the web and in the report therefore I need to replace **?** with parameters.

However, I can't use **replace*** method because **?** is special character for regex. I also don't want to use **String.format** method.

I know it is possible to replace **?** but I don't remember how.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: replace does not use regex but will replace both `?`.

Comment: I guess for better visibility instead of replace* I should have put replaceFirst and replaceAll

Comment: Simply escape ? when using regex using \.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
String message = "This is a test message. Generated for ? on ?";
message = message.replaceFirst("\\?", "Bob").replaceFirst("\\?", "Tuesday");
System.out.println(message);  // This is a test message. Generated for Bob on Tuesday
```

Comment: Now that was stupid on my part I forgot to do assignment in my code